# Php DOMDocument apply a query to a sub node instead of full xPath

Tags: php, domdocument

I have an HTML code having a list of items just like:

```
 <div id="page">
      <div class="item">
          <span class='subItem'>Item 1.1</span>
          <span class='subItem'>Item 1.2</span>
      </div>

    <div class="item">
          <span class='subItem'>Item 2.1</span>
      </div>

     <div class="item">
          <span class='subItem'>Item 3.1</span>
          <span class='subItem'>Item 3.2</span>
          <span class='subItem'>Item 3.3</span>
      </div>
 </div>
```

According to other answers here on Stackoverflow to get nodes by class name I use a method like:

```
 private function getItemsByClass($xpath, $el, $classname){
    $nodes = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]", $el);
    return $nodes;
 }
```

My intention is to extract a list of items from my code and then for **each item** get elements by class name.

Example: I get all the items having class "item"

```
    $xpath = new \DomXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $this->getItemsByClass($xpath, null, "item");
```

Then for each item, I would like the first element having class "subItem".

```
 foreach ($nodes as $node) {

      echo  $this->getItemsByClass($xpath, $node, "subItem")[0]->nodeValue;

 }
```

My code not works: it returns always the first element of $xpath, not of current $node

From [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) I'm trying to use the *DOMNode $contextnode*.

What I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

In the documentation [there is a note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php#99760):

> If the query() function seems to ignore your $contextnode, and instead returns all the tags in the document, try to use a relative path (use a . in front of the query):

So my query should be:

```
 if ($el) {
   $nodes = $xpath->query(".//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]", $el);
  } else {
   $nodes = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]", $el);
  }
```

**UPDATE 2**

I had two issues: the bug fixed with a relative path and the class name. Iw was catching also other elements having a similar class name. This second one was fixed with a new expression:

> $expression = './/'.$el.'[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " '.$classname.' ")]';
>           $nodes = $xpath->query($expression, $node);

Note: *the $classname had empty spaces at starting and end*.

Comment: Can you include some example HTML which can help test any solution.

Comment: @NigelRen Hi Nigel, just  updated

Comment: You found the answer, the duplicate is saying exactly the same.

Comment: You are passing `$xpath` everytime in the loop and running `getItemsByClass`. I think eventually you want to run it only once right? Something like `foreach ($xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'item')]") as $node) {`

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks for your help. I found my issue: there were into the code other classes similar to "item" but I need to catch exactly "item" class! So I was looking for in a bad direction...